# ggplot2 - How to apply a manual gradient with a legend when dot plot isn't coloring points at the same coordinates

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gradient, legend

I know I'm using the dotplot in a slightly odd way, but I've got it producing the graphic I want; which shows how many players in each position each Premier League football club has, with each dot showing one player. I have multiple categories - showing whether the player is a squad player or a youth player, these are plotted separately, with the second nudged down so they don't overlap.

I want to add another layer of information to it, which is shading the dots based on how many minutes each player has played. I have this data in my data frame.

It colour codes the dots perfectly, except when the data is "grouped", in which case it leaves it grey.

[image: screenshot of my plot]

I've read the guidance on producing a good r question. I've cut down the data to show the problem, without being huge, and removed all lines of code such as manipulating the data to this point and graph titles etc.

This is a sample of 20 players, which produces 16 nicely coloured dots, and 2 pairs of gray, uncoloured dots.

```
structure(list(team = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("AFC Bournemouth", "Arsenal", "Brighton & Hove Albion", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", "Huddersfield Town", "Leicester City", "Liverpool", "Swansea City", "Tottenham Hotspur", "West Bromwich Albion"), class = "factor"), 
role = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "U21", class = "factor"), 
name = structure(c(10L, 2L, 1L, 15L, 13L, 19L, 4L, 7L, 20L, 
8L, 17L, 9L, 18L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 14L, 5L, 12L, 16L), .Label = c("Boga", 
"Brown", "Burke", "Chilwell", "Christensen", "Field", "Grujic", 
"Harper", "Holgate", "Iwobi", "Junior Luz Sanches", "Loftus Cheek", 
"Lumeka", "Mousset", "Musonda", "Palmer", "Riedwald", "Sabiri", 
"Vlasic", "Walker-Peters"), class = "factor"), pos = structure(c(6L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2. CB", "3. LB", "3. RB", "4. CM", 
"5. AM", "5. WM", "6. CF"), class = "factor"), mins = c(11, 
24, 18, 1, 25, 10, 90, 6, 90, 20, 99, 180, 97, 127, 35, 156, 
32, 162, 258, 124)), .Names = c("team", "role", "name", "pos", "mins"), row.names = 471:490, class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+ 
 geom_dotplot(data=u21, aes(x=team, y=pos, fill=mins), binaxis='y', stackdir="center", stackratio = 1, dotsize = 0.1, binwidth=0.75, position=position_nudge(y=-0.1)) +
 scale_fill_gradient(low="pink",high='red')
```

In my actual code I then run the ggplot line again, but calling a different data frame, with a different colour gradient, and a different nudge so the dots don't overlap.

Answer (score 4):

Basically what's happening is those "grouped" dots are being treated as NA values because ggplot is receiving two min values for the same x,y coordinates, which is breaking the coloring mechanism. For example, at the intersect of "team=Chelsea" and "pos=5. WM", there are two mins: 18 and 1. The following code/graph changes NA values from the default of grey to yellow to show what's happening:

```
ggplot()+ 
  geom_dotplot(data=df, aes(x=team, y=pos, fill=mins), 
               binaxis='y', stackdir="center", 
               stackratio = 1, dotsize = 0.2, binwidth=0.75, 
               position=position_nudge(y=-0.1)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="pink",high='red',na.value="yellow") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.2, hjust=1, size=8))
```

Output:

[image]

This was a creative test of geom_dotplot. It's not that you can't do what you're asking for with that method, but it will be overly complicated to get the effect that you want with that approach. Instead, you might have more luck with geom_jitter, which was designed to handle plotting this type of data.

```
ggplot(df)+ 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=team, y=pos, col=mins),width = 0.2, height = 0) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="pink",high='red',na.value="yellow") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.2, hjust=1, size=8))
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you still want the complicated version with dotplot, avoiding jitter, then here's that too:

```
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("pink","red"))

df$cols <- cols(
  max(df$mins,na.rm=T))[findInterval(df$mins,sort(1:max(df$mins,na.rm=T)))]

ggplot()+ 
  geom_dotplot(data=df, aes(x=team, y=pos, col=mins, fill=cols), 
               binaxis='y',stackdir="centerwhole",stackgroups=TRUE, 
               binpositions="all",stackratio=1,dotsize=0.2,binwidth=0.75, 
               position=position_nudge(y=-0.1)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="pink",high='red',na.value="yellow") +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.2, hjust=1, size=8))
```

Output:

[image]

For those less familiar with what's going on in the code for the third graph: step 1 is to store a gradient range with colorRampPalette; step 2 carefully assigns a hexadecimal color value to each row according to the row's df$mins value; step 3 plots the data using both color and fill arguments set so that a legend appears, yet the otherwise grey (or yellow) grouped dots are overlaid by the correct manual gradient color we've set by calling scale_fill_identity(). With this configuration, you get the right color and the right legend.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, it does work on that sample, but when I try it on the full dataframe (~around 460 points), it looks very mess, as due to the random nature of jitter sometimes 3 players take up more space than 4, so the visual loses the 'at a glance' nature. Colour coding errors is a great idea for problem solving though. Thanks @RyanRunge

Comment: @ChrisBaker - Fair enough. I decided to add the complicated option to help in your specific use case. See the edit above.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - Please remember to click the check mark next to this solution if it's answered your question. It helps the community know it's been solved, and it helps others with the same question find their answer even faster.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I ran it late last night, but unfortunately it ended up really messy with the full data set, with the dots not lined up vertically at all. I tried to replicate it just now to take a screenshot, but now I get this error running the second line. Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cols, value = c("#FFB8C2", "#FFBCC7",  : 
  replacement has 378 rows, data has 513 .     Thanks for all your help, as you can see I'm pretty new to this!